# How to download more images in Android Application?

Tags: android

I am new to Android. Which is the better way to download more than 10 images from web service very quickly and while downloading i want to show a progress dialog and after downloading i want to dismiss the progress dialog. Can anyone send me the related information to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use the [AsyncTask class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It makes it very easy to run long operations, whilst updating the UI, but without locking up the app.

It's worth considering whether to download the images in series (one after another) or in parallel (with several AsyncTask objects for example). Doing them all at once will be faster, but will likely affect the phone performance and the network availability for other apps.

Comment: Hi Ollie C,Can u send me some code snippet which would be very helpful to me.

Comment: Try this http://ivolo.mit.edu/post/Android-Asynchronous-Image-Loading-or-e2809cLazy-Loade2809d.aspx

Comment: Hi Ollie, I used AsyncTask class to download images, i am displaying them in a gridview, but each time it displaying in different order. But i want to display in a an order as i passed the image urls..?How can i do that?

Comment: I think you should ask that as a new question

Comment: Hi,  I got the solution, I used AsynTask and Handler class. Now they are coming in order.